# Using a map on RVIZ

Tags: ros, arbotix

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,I follow the book [Ros By Example](http://wiki.ros.org/Books/ROSbyExample).I use  the method mentioned in this book to generating a map with the XV_11 laser scanner.And it seems that the `my_map.pgm` is 4.1MByte, and when I load this map,RVIZ becomes lagging.And warnnings show upon the terminal:

1、Control loop missed its desired rate:3.0 HZ,it actually takkes 1.3193s

2、Map update missed its desired rate:3.0 HZ,it actually takes 25.098s

Why? I just changed the test_map.pgm with my_map.pgm.Using test_map.pgm is OK and works really well.Maybe it is because my_map.pgm is too big?(test_map.pgm is only 300KB)
So are there any ways to cut the .pgm file to a small size or just filter the white areas?(the scanned map`my_map.pgm`is 2048x2048,I think it is too large)

PS:I tried set the `update_frequency` in `local_costmap_params.yaml` to 1HZ,reduce the`height width` to `3.0*3.0`,reduce the `controller_frequency` in `base_local_planner_params.yaml` to 1HZ,but these didn't work.
paste my distro:`I run ros Hydro on a Vmware machine(Mem:3G,Cpucores:2),the host is I5-3230M RAM:8G 64bits Lenovo Y400`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261662/using-a-map-on-rviz/) by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2017-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK,guys.I actually solved this problem by this way: I open this `my_map.pgm` with PhotoShop.Then I aborted the none-blank areas,reduce it to 574x544pixels(300kb).And then,everything works fine after this.So,the reason is the map is too large for the Vmware machine to afford it.Should I close this question to show it solved?

---

Originally posted by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) with karma: 88 on 2017-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1